# OMNET++ 5.1.1 and Qt

Tags: qt, omnet++

I am installing OMNET++ 5.1.1. However, during the installation, it is reported that:

configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.

Then I download and install the Qt from https://www.qt.io/download/. But it still report the same problem. How can I solve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you could offer a few more details on your operating system. Further if you don't need the Qt environment you could indeed just disable it for the installation as mentioned in the error.

Comment: Sorry, I forget it. The operating system is windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing OMNET++ on windows make sure you extract the zip file to a folder other than "Program Files" and deactivate your antivirus during the installation process.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're running some kind of GNU/Linux, because on Windows and macOS, the bundled Qt libraries should just work.

Try installing the Qt5 development packages using your distro's native package manager, then they should be detected.

If you can't, or they are too old, take a look in the `configure.user` file, and adjust the value of the `QT_PATH` variable according to the instructions there.

**EDIT**:

Since the OS was clarified: On Windows, you don't need to download Qt, or any other library separately. They are all bundled with the OMNeT++ distribution, and should work fine.

Just make sure you always use the included `mingwenv` shell to install and run OMNeT++. In it, the environment variables are set up as necessary.

Comment: I am sorry I forget the operating system. I install the omnet++ on windows 7.

Comment: I am getting the same error on Mac OS Mojave with qt5.14.1. Any tips?